# How can I store the files in my server after picking the files from dropbox with the dropbox Chooser using java

Tags: javascript, java, spring, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a form in my site. The forms allows the users either to select the files from their local machine or select the files from the drop box. I know how to get a file from the local machine and then store it in the server by doing and with a little bit of PHP stuff.

I did a research on drop box and found out that they have made something called 'Chooser - Dropbox'. (Basically, its a small JavaScript component that enables our web-app to get files from Dropbox ) and its pretty amazing that we can integrate 'Chooser' in our web.

But my problem is, I don't know how to store the files in my server after picking the files from dropbox with its Chooser.(I basically want to download that file and store in my server after picking the file from Chooser).

Here is the java-script that DropBox wants us to put in our web for the working of Chooser

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="YOUR_APP_KEY"></script>
```

Triggering the Chooser from JavaScript :

```
var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(button);
```

Here is options :

```
options = {

    // Required. Called when a user selects an item in the Chooser.
    success: function(files) {
        alert("Here's the file link: " + files[0].link)
    },

    cancel: function() {

    },

    linkType: "direct", // or "direct"

    multiselect: false, // or true

    extensions: ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx'],
};
```

In success callback i have a download link of file which we chosen from dropbox.

I'm using jquery in frontend and spring as backend.

Passing download link to java side and we can download dropbox file to local machine and again i can upload it to application server.

But is there a way to upload it to application server without download file into local machine.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In success block i'm getting the file download link.

```
 success: function(files) {
        alert("Here's the file link: " + files[0].link)
    }
```

using ajax again, i'm passing this download link to spring controller, from controller to service class.

In service class using below code we can save the file to server path.

```
        File newFile = new File("here write server path");

        if(!newFile.exists()){
            URL url = new URL(downloadLink);
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fos.close();
            rbc.close();
        }
```